# In spring boot 2 whats the most efficient way to log body?

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, jax-rs, spring-boot-actuator

I used to log my requests in filters in JAX-RS using this

```
@Provider
public class RequestLoggingFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    @Context
    private HttpServletRequest servletRequest;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {

        BufferedInputStream stream = new 
        BufferedInputStream(requestContext.getEntityStream());
        String payload = IOUtils.toString(stream, "UTF-8");
        requestContext.setEntityStream(IOUtils.toInputStream(payload, "UTF-8"));
    }

}
```

I am trying do something similar in spring boot 2 and I have tried using filters, Interceptors and also actuator. I lost the body as soon as I read it. In spring boot 2 the actuator's trace does not support logging of the body so is there any other way to log the request and response body without losing it?

Comment: You can just use the [Jersey LoggingFeature](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/logging_chapter.html). There are configuration options to log the body (based on the verbosity)

Answer (score 0):

You might find everything you need there: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-http-logging

> Spring provides a built-in solution to log payloads. We can use
>   ready-made filters by plugging into Spring application using
>   configuration.
>
> AbstractRequestLoggingFilter is a filter which provides basic
>   functions of logging. Subclasses should override the beforeRequest()
>   and afterRequest() methods to perform the actual logging around the
>   request.
>
> Spring framework provides three concrete implementation classes which
>   can be used to log the incoming request. These three classes are:
>
> CommonsRequestLoggingFilter Log4jNestedDiagnosticContextFilter
>   (deprecated) ServletContextRequestLoggingFilter Now, let’s move on to
>   the CommonsRequestLoggingFilter and configure it to capture incoming
>   request for logging.

Comment: I see CommonsRequestLoggingFilter does log the request, but as in that link I did try to override the beforeRequest in CustomeRequestLoggingFilter which pretty much does not work. The CommonsRequestLoggingFilter  gets called even though that function is overridden